# What is it called when an improper meaning becomes the only meaning of a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone else asked [Are camp followers prostitutes?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90741/are-camp-followers-prostitutes) and the answer seems to be that while not every one who follows a military camp is a prostitute, if you *aren't* referring to a prostitute, you should probably pick another label for the person.

A similar effect can be seen with sexually themed words like "mistress", "madam", "ejaculate", and "escort".

I assume this linguistic process has been studied and I'm curious what its name is.

Comment: I don't see where you got your "answer seems to be..." idea from. The only person suggesting that was the original OP - both in the question, and in his own answer to it (which currently has *no* upvotes). All other comments and answers pretty much agree with [the top-rated answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90742/2637), which says *the term can be used in non-military contexts in which there is clearly no improper suggestion*. Which is not to say other examples don't exist - just that "camp followers" isn't a particularly good one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’ve heard that Judy Garland has camp followers, too. :)

Comment: It's called "language change" or "lexical evolution" or "a word means what the users understand it to mean" or "descriptivist evolution". Just depends on whether you're reactionary & ultra-orthodox or tuned in to what people say & what they mean by it. I don't agree that when only one of many possible meanings becomes the only _current_ meaning of a word, that the meaning is "improper", just _tendentious_. Word meanings broaden & narrow over time as well as with the dominant ideology in a social group. "Improper" is, strictly, a moral judgment, but language, like Nature, is amoral.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the *[euphemism treadmill](http://englishcowpath.blogspot.com/2011/06/euphemism-treadmill-replacing-r-word.html)*.

Comment: Useful wiki on *misnomer* here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer

Comment: This intercourse is rather fascinating to watch...

Comment: @BillFranke - "Improper" is a moral judgment, but it's not *my* moral judgment.  This process occurs with the society regards something as improper.  When I was younger, people whose job it was to walk women to their cars at night would describe themselves as "escorts".  I'm guessing they don't do that any more.

Comment: Yes, the default meaning of the noun _escort_'s changed, so using it doesn't work well unless one wants to make a statement about the escort & the escorted. Language is amoral, but people are, statistically, normally moralistic. Even heinous criminals have the nerve to judge the acts of others as good & bad. Words matter, but not everyone cares that they do, & even some of those who do care don't understand why they matter, nor do they always understand what words matter in every context, but I suppose that no one can be that prescient. Many words are best left unspoken & unwritten.

Answer (score 2):

That is the opposite of euphemism. Not the opposite meaning, but the opposite dynamics - not substituting a term but allowing the meaning of a term to deteriorate.

Euphemism - substituting a gentler word to describe an unpleasant situation or environment.

Anti-euphemism - the deteriorated association of a term due to its usual and persistent usage.

What I am thinking are the words **dysphemism** - deteriorated reputation, and **pejoration**, having a few modes of dynamics:

1. Pejoration - a word having gone thro deterioration and applying that deteriorated word pejoratively (e.g. retard, unique, the n-word, the fag-word)
2. Pejoration - an euphemism evolving into dysphemism, due to basic unpleasant application of the word (e.g. toilet)
3. using an immutably unpleasant word pejoratively (e.g. You are full of sh!t)

Examples of dysphemistic deterioration (i.e., pejoration) of words:

- The word **toilet** in American English. Toilet was meant to be an euphemism for a smelly room because "toilet" actually means "dressing room".

  Hence, "You smell like a toilet." Perhaps, one day we will witness the pejoration of the meaning of the phrase "You smell like a bathroom" in American English.
- The boy has **unique** qualities. **Retarded** children. - these used to be pleasant euphemism, but their use have deteriorated due to the basic negative association society has on the subjects they describe.

Perhaps, as purported, the pejoration of the word **camp-followers** due to the following process

1. Using **camp-followers** euphemistically to denote prostitutes.
2. Due to the basic negative subject, the phrase **camp-followers** pejorates.
3. The reversed polarity due to pejoration, the phrase is now a dysphemism.

---

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pejoration

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pejoration

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism

Comment: +1 Interesting stuff. I'm not sure I understand your example of _unique_ and _retarded_. Were they pleasant euphemisms?

Comment: If you are older than 60, retarded would be an euphemism during the days of your childhood. "Unique" has been used pejoratively in the recent decade.

Comment: Children of retarded development used to he a way to pleasantly describe certain children.

Comment: @BlessedGeek -- I've never heard "unique" used as an insult, but "special" is definitely trotting down the euphemism treadmill.

Answer (score 2):

What appears to have happened in the case of words like *camp followers*, *gay*, *ejaculate*, etc. is a *narrowing* or *specialisation* of their meanings.

[Semantic narrowing](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/semnarrterm.htm):

> "Narrowing of meaning. This happens when a word with a general meaning is by degrees applied to something much more specific. The word litter, for example, meant originally (before 1300) 'a bed,' then gradually narrowed down to 'bedding,' then to 'animals on a bedding of straw,' and finally to things scattered about, odds and ends. ... Other examples of specialization are deer, which originally had the general meaning 'animal,' girl, which meant originally 'a young person,' and meat, whose original meaning was 'food.'"
>
> (Sol Steinmetz, Semantic Antics: How and Why Words Change Meanings. Random House, 2008)

Semantic *broadening*, as it were, is referred to as [semantic bleaching](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Bleaching.htm).

Comment: I can't seem to agree that *narrowing* or *bleaching* could imply taking on something that wasn't there in the first place. Worse still, something quite contrary to what was.

Comment: @Kris For example?

Comment: As in OP's. Originally, *camp follower* did not mean a prostitute. The *de facto* meaning today (if the argument is correct) is contrary to the original meaning.

Comment: @Kris IMO, originally _camp followers_ referred to those who followed a camp. It then appears to have become specific to military camps  with camp followers _including_, amongst others, prostitutes. It has since devolved to only refer to prostitutes. This fits in well with _semantic narrowing_.

Comment: It's neither narrowing nor broadening but semantic corruption.

Comment: Frank Zappa: What I think is very cynical about some rock and roll songs is the way they say "Let's make love." You ought to be able to say "Let's go f**k," but ... to get on the radio. This creates a semantic corruption (of the) word "love" in the song. 
http://books.google.com/books?id=uAYfqgGf4yYC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=semantic+corruption&source=bl&ots=VI6wjP0BWO&sig=iPu5nj1QOyJ8LAr6AyKnjAW3qUQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dmysUO2fH4rprAfet4DgCQ&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBQ