# How do words become derogatory or politically incorrect?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, politeness, pejorative-language, political-correctness

I know how words can become racist but I'm not sure how a word becomes derogatory or politically incorrect. If seems as though once one does, a new term is created to replace it that is not derogatory and is politically acceptable. But those new words and terms often times become derogatory or politically incorrect over time.

For example, the way crippled gave way to handicapped, which gave way to disabled.

Comment: And the 'savage' has given way to 'tribal man' or 'primitive man'.

Comment: It's [political correctness gone mad!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_correctness#Current_usage)

Comment: My hunch is that, as long as the discrimination still exists, then whatever term happens to be in vogue for describing the discriminated-against group will eventually become associated with the negatives associated with the stereotype, and will fall out of favour. It then gets replaced by a "better" term, but since the prejudice is still there, the term loses its sheen over time and becomes a negative term... And so on.

Comment: Also called the *euphemism treadmill*.

Comment: Related: [What is it called when an improper meaning becomes the only meaning of a word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91836/what-is-it-called-when-an-improper-meaning-becomes-the-only-meaning-of-a-word)

Comment: @JAM Which is now *differently abled*.

Comment: @MετάEd, I've heard people bandy about "differently abled," but I've never heard it used seriously. Have you?

Comment: @JAM I'm Unitarian. If that isn't enough information, Google [ [unitarian differently abled](http://www.google.com/search?q=unitarian+differently+abled) ]. Welcome to the bleeding edge of compassionate language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The linguistic processes are technically called **Taboo** (in this case, Taboo **words**) and [**Euphemism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism), which is substituting a non-taboo word for a taboo word, like saying

- *What the heck*

intead of

- *What [the hell](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/thehell.html)*.

The way it happens is that there are always taboos on certain terms and topics in every culture. These taboo words are the healthiest words in the language, because everybody has to know them, in order to avoid saying them.

> (If this sounds crazy, that's because it is -- taboos are unconscious, and not really subject to logic. After all, words by themselves have no powers; it's human culture that produces taboos.)

Anyway, people **do** need to talk about things, even if it's forbidden, so we substitute "safe" terms (like *water closet* or *crapper* or *toilet* or *washroom* or *men's room* or *bathroom*, instead of "place where one shits in private"). These euphemisms have a short half-life, since once the substitution strategy is detected, the euphemism gradually becomes taboo itself, and is replaced by another euphemism, while the original taboo term goes on forever.

*Derogatory, politically (in)correct, profane, vulgar, racist, sexist,* and other terms that are applied to language chunks are simply descriptions of the variety of taboo that the terms  in question are said to be breaking. They're not categories of words so much as social infractions, which is (luckily) not a matter of grammar.