# Does "what on earth" work same with "what-the-hell"?

Tags: word-usage

Does "what on earth" work same with "what-the-hell" ?

Answer (score 3):

In short: yes and no.

The definitions for **[what the hell](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What+the+hell%3F)** and **[what on earth](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/what+on+earth)** both state that they are:

> *An exclamation used to emphasize surprise, shock, anger, disgust, etc.*

However, **what the hell** uses the word **hell** as an intensifier, giving it much more emotional impact compared to **what on earth**.

**what the hell** can also mean:

> *Why not; one might as well; it makes no difference anyway.*

An example:

> **A**: Do you think we can add some extra effects to this scene?
>
> **B**: Sure, what the hell. It's not like we're short on funds or anything.

So, in summation, when it comes to expressing shock, they are pretty much interchangeable, though **what the hell** should be used if you want to give your speech a bit more oomph. If life requires you to not give a damn about anything, then use **what the hell**, but not **what on earth**.

Answer (score 1):

*What on Earth* is a [euphemism](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/93492/15299) for the taboo phrase *What [the Hell](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html)*, in most environments.
I wouldn't say they work the same, though. The reason you use one is to avoid using the other.
Therefore which one you use makes a difference, and has an effect.